# Copying files in devel folder - CMakeLists.txt

Tags: catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

My application requires a configuration file and a resource folder placed in the same directory as the executable. Those are located at : `~/workspace/src/project/cfg/`. I want to copy this file and this directory at `~/workspace/devel/lib/project/`, where my executable is located.

What can I add to my CMakeLists.txt to achieve that? I have tried using `${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}`, but it creates a `lib` subdirectory in `build`.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/182465/copying-files-in-devel-folder---cmakelists.txt/) by [gariepya](https://answers.ros.org/users/19385/gariepya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2014-07-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION` variable only contains a relative path. You need to additionally use `CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX`. So combined you want to install to:

```
"${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}`
```

which will be:

```
<develspace>/lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
```

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-07-02**:
`BIN_DESTINATION` twice?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-07-03**:
Sorry, that was a copy-n-paste error - I updated the answer.

**Comment by [gariepya](https://answers.ros.org/users/19385/gariepya/) on 2014-07-03**:
Thank you! I miss it in the documentation for some reason,..

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2019-04-11**:
I get something weird with  "${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}"
I am getting this:

/.private//lib/

I really would like to get:
/.private//lib/

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-04-11**:
Instead of commenting on a 5 years old answered question please ask your own question with enough information.